# Laravel polymorphic relationship - Alert system

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models, `User`, `Alert`, and `Category`.

The relationship between `User` and `Category` is many-to-many.

The relationship between `Alert` and `Category` is also many-to-many.

A `User` should only receive `Alert` that belongs to the same `Category` which the `User` have selected. e.g. If the `User` have **Travel** and **Food** as the `Category`, then I'd like only `Alert` with **Travel** and **Food** to be shown to the `User`.

Once the `User` views an `Alert`, the `Alert` should be marked as 'read' for that particular `User`.

Currently I'm doing it like so:

```
Category.php

public function alerts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Alert')->withTimestamps();
}

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps();
}
```

```
User.php

public function alerts()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
}

public function categories()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany('App\Alert')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('read');
}
```

```
Alert.php

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User')->withTimestamps()->withPivot('read');
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category')->withTimestamps();
}
```

With this current implementation, there are 3 pivot tables: `alert_category`, `alert_user`, and `category_user`. `alert_user` table has an extra field named `read` which basically determines if the user has read the alert or not. i.e.

```
alert_user table

alert_id
user_id
read (holds 0 or 1)
```

This implementation have many flaws, and I don't think it's even working at all, since new `User` won't receive `Alert` that were created before they registered, and if `Alert` changes `Category`, it won't be updated. Of course, it could be done by explicitly updating each table, but I don't believe that's efficient nor is it architecture.

I'm thinking of refactoring the whole thing into a many-to-many polymorphic relationship. But, how would I determine if the `User` has read a particular `Alert`? Where should I place a `read` field?

What do you think? I'm open to any ideas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit:**

To summarise, I guess what I'm trying to do is, instead of `User` subscribing to `Alert`, it should instead subscribe to `Category`. Therefore, essentially the `User` will receive all `Alert` of the same `Category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the newly registered users to see all previous alerts under chosen categories, it's basically saying that a logged in user should see all alerts under those categories.

I do not think that associating an `alert` with a `user` will give you any sort of advantage. If any, it is giving you an extra layer of complexity.

Now, if you want to keep track of which `users` read which `alert`, you could use the `alert_user` table. Basically, you create this relationship when a `user` reads an `alert`. `created_at` will tell you the exact time the user read the `alert` and, therefore, a `read` flag is not necessary as well.

And, to display the alerts, you could query, for example, the alerts that does not have relationship records with the logged in user. You could use `whereDoesntHave`. For example, something like this:

```
Alert::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_id_array){

  $query->whereIn('category_id', $category_id_array);

})->whereDoesntHave('users', function($query) use ($user_id){

  $query->where('user_id', $user_id); //user_id is auth()->user()->id

})->get();
```

If you only want to display the tweets without excluding the authenticated user:

```
Alert::whereHas('categories', function($query) use ($category_id_array){

  $query->whereIn('category_id', $category_id_array);

})->get();
```

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, `Alert` should not be assigned to `User`, instead `User` should subscribe to `Category` and receive `Alert` of the same `Category`. I've updated my question. But I've no idea how to implement this. Anyway, yours seems interesting, I'll see if I can make it work.
**Edit:** also, I do want newly registered users to see all alerts that are relevant to them. I've set so that the alerts automatically expire so they'll eventually be deleted.

Comment: Also, I want logged in users to see the alerts. The app I'm making requires all users to be logged in.

Comment: New update makes so much more sense. I don't think you'll need to change schema or relationships. The only difference is, the `user` in `Alert` is now users who read the alert. So you might want to rename the function for readability. Same goes to alert method in `User`. About new users, how do you identify `relevant` alerts? I would assume that, a `User` would need to subscribe to `Category` to see alerts..?

Comment: Yes, `User` would need to subscribe to one or more `Category`. So for example, the new `User` subscribes to **Food** and **Travel** `Category`, so they'll only see alerts which have `Category` **Food** and **Travel**, both new and those created before the `User` registered.

Comment: In that case this should work. You get the subscribed category ids before querying for `Alert`.

Answer (score 0):

If your wish is to select a user and *then* determine if he has any unread alerts, then you could to something like this:

```
foreach($user->alerts as $alert){
 if($alert->read == 1){
  //do something with that particular alert
 }
}
```

If you want to determine if a particular alert has been read, you can search for it like this:

```
Alert::where('id', '=', $alert_id)->where('read', '=', 1)->first(); 
//will return alert or null
```

Comment: This is what I'm currently doing. It's not flexible. This would be fine if there's no `Category`.